# After iOS 17 Widgets + Extensions get the local form device language not from the app

Tags: localization, widget, ios17

I am experiencing a problem with iOS 17, where the Widgets and Extensions adopt the local device language instead of the app language. This issue was present in iOS 16.1 previously, but Apple resolved it later. Now it back on iOS 17 and iOS 17.1

Are you encountering the same problem? Has anyone found a solution for this?